# PHP crashing during oAuth scripts

Tags: php, centos, nginx, php-fpm, oauth

I just installed Nginx 1.2.4 and PHP 5.4.0 (from svn) (php fpm). *CentOs 5.8 64*

The problem I have is that PHP crashes the moment I run any social oAuth scripts. I have tried to log into Facebook, Twitter and Google with various scripts that I know work on my other servers. When I load the scripts I get a 502 error from Nginx. And I find these errors in the log:

in php-fpm log:

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 23821 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 1132.862984 seconds from start
```

in nginx log:

```
ERROR: recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

From what I can see, it goes wrong when PHP tries to make a request to any of the oAuth servers.

https://github.com/mahmudahsan/PHP-SDK-3.0---Graph-API-base-Facebook-Connect-Tutorial-Source for example is one of the scripts that works perfectly on my other machines, but causes PHP to crash.

I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616191/nginx-php-fpm-502-bad-gateway which seems to be a similar problem, but I cannot find a way to solve it.

**+++ UPDATE +++**

Now I have been doing some debugging in 1 of the scripts that is playing up.

If you go to line 808 http://pastebin.com/gSnzRtXb it runs the curl_exec()
command.

When that is ran, it crashes. If i echo'test';exit; just above that line, it
echo's correctly, if i do it below that line, php crashes.

Which means it's that line 808 which causes the crash.

So I made a very simple script to do some testing: http://pastebin.com/Rshnyhcm
which also uses curl_exec, but that runs just fine.

So I started to dig deeper into that query from the facebook script to see what
values the $opts array contains from line 806.

Output of that array is: http://pastebin.com/Cq9ffd3R

What the problem is, I still have no clue :(

Comment: Your problem sounds like a mismatch between libcurl version and php-curl module.  Do you have more than one libcurl installed?  When you compiled PHP it may have used a different version of libcurl than the one it's trying to use now.

Comment: How could I find out if this is the case?

Comment: Did you say PHP 5.4.0? I'm quite sure there have been several bug-fix releases since then...

Comment: Found out what is causing the problem. cURL requests in PHP that request an https:// link cause PHP to crash. http:// links work fine. Weirdly enough cURL is configured with https support though: http://i.imgur.com/zfkj5.png so I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: That means it's likely a difference between libcurl's openssl library and either PHP or apache's openssl library

Comment: Hi DerfK, how could I check the difference between the libcurl and php openssl library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was solved by upgrading to PHP 5.4.8