# PHP does not allow https connections

Tags: php, centos, nginx, https, php-fpm

Hey guys im running PHP 5.4.0 and I cannot cURL nor files_get_content() https connections.

Using curl in a PHP script shows:

```
[root@ns1]# /opt/php/bin/php -q test.php
* About to connect() to www.google.com port 443
*  Trying 74.125.225.210... * connected
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.225.210) port 443
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
Segmentation fault
```

Using file_get_contents() shows:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did
you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in /test.php
```

OpenSSL and OpenSSL-devel are installed, and PHP is also configured with cURL support for SSL connections. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCJNF.png

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Further info: CentOS 5.8(64) with Nginx 1.2.4

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/443363/php-crashing-during-oauth-scripts#comment479809_443363

Comment: Yes 5.4.0 isn't the newest version, but it is the newest version via SVN. And because it is currently a LIVE production server, I prefer not to upgrade PHP entirely as it will mean serious downtime.

Comment: Have you followed through [this question for the file_get_contents() problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that was a fix for windows, where simple ddl files could be added to the php.ini file.

Comment: Under Linux, the extensions still need to be loaded in your `php.ini` but the file extension is `.so` instead of `.dll`.

Comment: Problem is, there is no php_openssl.so to be found. Not on my server, and also not online. I have looked everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by upgrading to 5.4.8.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try compiling PHP from source using --with-openssl --with-curl (an your other requirements). It will guarantee that Curl and PHP are speaking the same versions.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 5.4.9 did it for me.  There is apparently a bug with 5.4.4.

Comment: This answer would be improved with a supporting reference like a bugzilla ticket/issue.